# How to show button when adding fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Bottom button(234) is not showing after adding fragment. I don't want to resize my fragment size.

[image: Viewpager Front page]

[image: After Adding Fragment]

**Home_Fragment.xml** This is the main Fragment page. It also have profile Fragment. From Profile Fragment we are calling next fragment that is hiding bottom button (TV_Chat button name)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <!-- View pager to swipe views -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="" />

    <com.medyc.us.customViews.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:background="@color/light_background"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tv_chat"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_blue_gradient"
        android:text="234"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/twenty_sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/thirty_dp"
        />
    <!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide full code with your question, it looks like you can use button.bringToFront() function to solve your problem

Comment: @HamzaIqbal i tried it..but it's not working

Comment: Please Add XML and Java code with your question

Comment: Does your button(234) belongs to activity? If yes provide the activity layout file also

Comment: Code added. @jubayer

Comment: Home_Fragment.xml is your activity layout file?

Comment: yes but it my main fragment file.

Comment: anyone knows ? ...

Comment: @RohitShrivastava have you tried **FrameLayout** ? The document says _Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top._ You can refer it here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout might this solve your problem.